# issues with deques and exceeding deque size with index operator

Tags: c++, stl, deque

Having a strange issue with deques in C++.
Let's say I have a deque of doubles of size 4.  For some reason, when using the index operator, I seem to be able to exceed the size of the deque.
In other words, neither the compiler nor the program at execution will barf if I write the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    x[i] = (double)(i*i);
    cout << x[i] << endl;
}
```

Where x is the deque.  And I actually am able to get outputs from this.
It doesn't increase the size of the deque.  If I output x.size(), I still get 4.
What gives?
I'm using Code::Blocks with the standard default gcc compiler that comes with it.

Comment: By going out of bounds you are invoking undefined behaviour, at which point your program is allowed to do anything, including erasing your hard drive.

Comment: The same thing would happen with a regular array. Why are you surprised?

Comment: `neither the compiler`  How is the compiler to know that there are only 4 items?  `nor the program at execution will barf if I write the following`  I'll ask you -- what do you mean by "execution will barf"?  If you can't answer that question, then your non-answer *is* the answer.  No one knows what the program will do when you do things like this.  That's what you call "undefined behavior".

Comment: Normally, when I've dealt with this in the past, either the compiler will complain, or the program will give me some sort of exception at runtime.  This did neither.  For a deque of size 4, and with going from i = 0 to 6, it returned: x[0] = 0, x[1] = 1, x[2] =  4, x[3] =  9, x[4] = 16, x[5] = 25, x[6] = 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing out of bounds gives undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Many containers will round the current size up to some convenient value (e.g., a power of 2), so depending on the current size you'll have some amount of memory after the last item in the collection. Indexing into that memory and attempting to read it will produce some result, but the memory is typically uninitialized, so the result will often be meaningless and invalid (and, although most don't, the container could do bounds checking, and throw an exception or almost anything else when you index out of bounds).

IMO, `at` is a fairly poor tool to deal with the possibility though. A better way to avoid such problems is a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto &d : x) {
    d = d * d;
    std::cout << d << "\n"; // avoid `endl`, which flushes the stream.
}
```

Another possibility would be to use standard algorithms:

```
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](double d) { return d*d; });
std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

There are also range-based algorithms (e.g., one set in Boost, at least one more being suggested for a future C++ standard), that (do/would) allow something on the general order of:

```
copy(x, output_range<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Since this figures out the bounds of `x` on its own, short of a bug in the code for the range, it's pretty much impossible to accidentally index out of bounds this way.

Answer (score 3):

`operator[]` does not bounds check, just like when using a raw array.  the `at` member function does, if you instead use

```
x.at(i);
```

you will get a `std::out_of_range` exception if you exceed the bounds of the `deque`.  If you run your original code through a memory error checker (like valgrind) you will see "invalid read" and "invalid write" errors.

If you look at [cppreference's docs on operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator_at) you'll see the note "No bounds checking is performed."

However [the docs for at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/at) say

> If pos not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown

Going out of bounds on a container is undefined behavior.  If you are accessing with an index where you aren't sure if it's in-bounds or not, it's your job to either check that it is, or use `at` and possibly handle the exception.